# Parking in Copenhagen

Tags: automobiles, denmark, copenhagen

I can find lots of information online about using the public transportation in Copenhagen but almost none about how parking works. Everyone just says it's very hard and I should not try it but I am afraid that's unavoidable for me next week.

How does parking work in Copenhagen? Do I need to know anything special about the way I'm allowed to park?

Comment: I once drove to Copenhagen by car and had to park next to the Tivoli. With the help of my GPS it wasn't too difficult to find a parking garage. However, it was a little bit weird, since I had to give the guy how monitored this parking garage my key. First I wasn't sure if this is a good idea, but then I just took all my valuables out of the car and gave him the key. Later I was told that this is usual in Scandinavia. But I can't confirm it because it was the only time I parked in a parking garage and not somewhere else in Denmark. The price was also quite high, but compared to my place not.

Comment: , that's why I did use this opportunity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got me curious so I decided to look into that.  There is apparently a whole set of sites dedicated to parking in Copenhagen, but I think that [this one](http://www.visitcopenhagen.com/good-to-know/practical-stuff/parking-in-copenhagen) provides a great aggregation of them.

Answer (score 4):

I know its been quite a while since the question has been asked, but if someone still finds this useful, here's my two cents.

I was in Denmark a few months ago, and parking in central Copenhagen can be really expensive. However, just outside the center it is not too difficult to find a cheap or if you are really lucky, a safe and free place to park your car and continue on public transport. [Visit Copenhagen](http://www.visitcopenhagen.com/copenhagen/parking-copenhagen) has some very valuable information about traveling and parking in Copenhagen.
I have not used it my self but a friend who was there for Christmas has found a mobile app which can be really useful in finding parks and public transport transits from there. Here's the link. [Copenhagen parking app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eunka.anjelloatoz.pplads&hl=en_GB)

Comment: These are useful 2 cents.