# Park and Ride in Copenhagen

Tags: public-transport, automobiles, copenhagen

We'll be five adults staying in Copenhagen from the evening of Sunday, May 5th until the morning of Wednesday, May 8th. Our approach will be via the E20 from the west. Since parking in Copenhagen proper is very expensive, I've been looking for a solution where we can park our car somewhere in the Copenhagen urban area for a reasonable price for those few days, and then get around by public transport.

I've found [Parking in Copenhagen](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/6262/parking-in-copenhagen), but its answers are quite old and have stale links.

Is there an "official" Park and Ride solution for my problem? If not, are there reasonably priced, not-too-busy parking opportunities near good public transport connections to the city centre?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look around on Street View, but it seems most of the big wide parking lots I was sure I remembered either are not there, or have been developed over, or have 3-hour limitations.

What immediately looks most promising are **Friheden** and **Åmarken** S-train stations in Hvidovre, which both have decent-sized free lots on the south/east side of the tracks. They're pretty close to the E20 motorway too. Trains go every 10 minutes during the day and take about 15 minutes to reach the city center.

It seems unlikely that all the spots will be taken on a Sunday evening, but if you'd like to have a plan C ready, the **Rødovre Centrum** shopping mall could be it. It boasts large free/unlimited parking structures, which I've never seen fully occupied on a Sunday.

The downside of Rødovre Centrum is that there's no train from there. You can take bus 9A to the metro terminus at Vanløse (expect about 25 minutes to the city center), or bus 6A all the way into the center (about 10 minutes slower but avoids the change).

Comment: We went for Åmarken, and it worked perfectly. Åmarken is within zones 1-4 of Copenhagen public transport, which puts it within range of a commutation ticket that we could buy at a vending machine directly at the station and then use for all public transport during our whole stay.

Comment: And the parking was free of charge? On Google maps there are two parking lots shown at Åmarken. Which one did you choose?

Comment: @StefanBorrmann At the time we were there, parking was free of charge. We used the "obvious" parking lot right at the station. The only other parking lot nearby I see on Google maps is "ParkZone Åmarkvej", on the other side of Åmarkvej. We haven't used that one, so I can't tell you whether it is free or not.

Comment: "ParkZone" sounds like one of the businesses that collect usage fees from privately-owned parking spaces. The P-signs there on Street View don't look like a public space either -- the blue is too dark.